# AMPscript to grab just first name from field with multiple names?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is it possible to display just a first name from a field that contains both first and last?

For example, I currently use something like this to display a first name:

```
%%[
set @First = [First Name]
]%%

%%=ProperCase(@First)=%%
```

In this case, if the First Name field is 'ROBERT', the email will display 'Robert'.

However, I have a field that contains first and last, but I only want to display first.

If the field contains 'ROBERT JOHNSON', is it possible to display just 'Robert' through AMPscript?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no risk free automated way to do this - each option involves the possibility that the name stored is incorrect.  Your best bet is to have your 'datasource of truth' separate this value and provide you with First and Last name fields instead of editing in SFMC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to find the index position of the whitespace, and then substring it which strips out the last name.

**You can do something like this:**

```
%%[
  SET @FullName = 'ROBERT JOHNSON'
  SET @WhiteSpacePos = IndexOf(@FullName, ' ')
  SET @FirstNamePos = Add(@WhiteSpacePos, 1)
  SET @FirstName = Substring(@FullName, 1, @FirstNamePos)
]%%

/* Print out the firstname string only */
Hello, %%=v(@FirstName)=%%
```

Refer to the [**AMPScript Syntax Guide**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/) for reference.

Comment: Be aware this can break up first names that have multiple parts. E.G. 'Jean Marie Person' would become just 'Jean'  as well your substring is for lastname - you are starting after the space and going for 100 characters - you need to start at 1 and max-length set at Index

Comment: You are right, definitely be mindful of multipart names. I have updated my answer to re adjust the Substring

Comment: I appreciate the advice and have solved the issue with a SQL query, instead of AMPscript to fix data.  The query I used probably won't help others as I was able to uncover another data extension we have with just a first name so was able to do a JOIN to import that data.  Appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short version I like to use -- one that checks for an existing space first:

```
%%[

var @full_name, @first_name
set @full_name = AttributeValue("full_name")
set @first_name = @full_name 

if indexOf(@full_name, " ") > 0 then
  set @first_name = substring(@full_name,1,subtract(indexOf(@full_name," "),1))
endif

]%%
```

**Reference**

- [**AttributeValue**](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue)
- [**IndexOf**](https://ampscript.guide/indexof)
- [**Substring**](https://ampscript.guide/substring)
- [**Subtract**](https://ampscript.guide/subtract)